# I can't alter two image variables out of Jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

i wrote this controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class cachecompanyController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('livewire.cache');
    }
    public function updatecache($id, Request $request){
        $validatedata = $request->validate([
            'cache'=> ['nullable', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png', 'max:2048'],
        ],
    );

        $user = User::find($id);

        if($request->hasFile('cache')){
        $user_img = $request->file('storage/cache');
        $name_gen = hexdec(uniqid()); 
        $image_ext = strtolower($user_img->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $image_name = $name_gen . '.' . $image_ext;
        $up_location = '/cache/';
        $last_img = $up_location . $image_name ;
        $user_img->move($up_location,$image_name);
        $user->cache_photo_path = $last_img;
        // dd("lightning");
        }

        $user->save();
    }
}
```

with these routes :

```
Route::get('cache-upload', [cachecompanyController::class, 'index'])-> Name('indexcache');
Route::post('/save-cache/{id}',[cachecompanyController::class, 'updatecache'])-> Name('updatecache');
```

and this layout:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('save-cache/'.$id = auth()->user()) }}"enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div>
      <input type="file" name="cache">
      <img class="image rounded-circle" name="cache" src="{{asset('/cache/')}}" alt="cache_photo_path"> 
      <input type="submit" value="Save" >
   </div>
</form>
```

, but when i upload it gives an empty page (error 404) and a link like this :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/save-cache/%7B%22id%22:1,%22name%22:%22Vitamedic%22,%22email%22:%22blackxdust@gmail.com%22,%22email_verified_at%22:null,%22current_team_id%22:1,%22profile_photo_path%22:%22profile-photos//n0TdjG3WXfJYDzxJBRcOaoRLIco0rBTdzPCvDYNi.png%22,%22cache_photo_path%22:null,%22companie_photo_path%22:null,%22created_at%22:%222021-11-21T20:55:17.000000Z%22,%22updated_at%22:%222021-11-24T13:30:18.000000Z%22,%22profile_photo_url%22:%22//storage//profile-photos//n0TdjG3WXfJYDzxJBRcOaoRLIco0rBTdzPCvDYNi.png%22%7D

what can I do to fix it ?